# Get the last nth day of previous month (pay period)

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

So the pay period is the 20th of every month. how can i get the last pay period's date? For example:

```
today: is 05/12 -> returns 04/20
today: is 05/20 -> returns 04/20
today: is 05/25 -> returns 05/20
```

how can I do that in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with a simple this:

```
$dayNow = date('d');
if($dayNow <= '20') {
    $previousDate = strtotime($dateNow.' -1 month');
    $date = date('Y-m', $previousDate);
} else {
    $date = date('Y-m');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to do things like "31st or last" or "2nd monday" I'd recommend using an rrule library like the following:

https://packagist.org/packages/rlanvin/php-rrule

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps there's a more elegant way, but this works (verbose for clarity):

```
function lastPayDate($todayDayNum) {
    $month = $todayDayNum > 20 ? 'this month' : 'last month';
    return (new \DateTimeImmutable('first day of ' . $month))
        ->add(new \DateInterval('P19D'));
}

echo lastPayDate(date('d'))->format('m/d/Y');
```